# How to retrieve data from sql/Mysql Query?

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join, where-clause

I want to retrieve data from sql query but I am not able to retrieve the data correctly.

I have two tables:

Table UserPost:

```
id       userID     postText         status
1        abc        hello world!     0
2        xyz        hello Test!      0
3        abc        hello Que!       0
4        qwe        hello All!       0
5        abc        hello Post!      0
6        rty        hello RTY!       0
7        jkl        hello JKL!       0
8        jkl        hello JKL2!      0
9        jkl        hello JKL3!      0
10       jkl        hello JKL4!      0
```

Table UserFollow:

```
id       followerID     followedID         status
1        abc            xyz                 1
2        xyz            qwe                 1
3        abc            rty                 1
4        qwe            abc                 1
5        abc            jkl                 1
```

I want to write a query to select posts from user and followed users

(Both USER And User's followers Post LIKE 'abc' and all posts whom 'abc' followed)

WHERE UserPost.Status = 0 AND UserFollow.status = 1

I have tried this but failed:

```
SELECT * FROM UserPost INNER JOIN UserFollow 
  ON UserPost.userID = UserFollow.followedID 
    WHERE UserFollow.followerID = 'abc' 
      AND UserFollow.status=1 
        AND UserPost.status=0

// This is not working
```

I tried with another query:

```
select p.*, u.* from ( select * from UserPost 
 where userID = 'abc'  or userID in (select followedID 
 from UserFollow where followedID = 'abc') ) p inner join UserFollow u 
 on u.followedID = p.userID order by p.id
// This query is also not working
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Sample table data is great, but also specify the expected result.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Specify the expected result, just like you've done with the sample data.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Put what is needed into your post, not just at some link. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you can use `exists`:

```
select p.*
from userpost p
where 
    p.status = 0
    and (
        p.userid = 'abc'
        or exists (
            select 1
            from userfollow f
            where f.follower_id = 'abc' and f.followedid = p.userid and f.status = 1
        )
    )
```

Comment: @SoniyaJain: just replace `select p.*` with `select count(*)`.

Comment: You are a real genius a real hero. Thanks a lot for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but the following is pretty intuitive.

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserPost 
where UserPost.status = 0
and (userID = 'abc'
      or UserID in (select followedID
                    from UserFollow
                    where followerID = 'abc'
                    AND status=1))
```

Which returns

```
id  userid  posttext    status
1   abc     hello world!    0
2   xyz     hello Test!     0
3   abc     hello Que!      0
5   abc     hello Post!     0
6   rty     hello RTY!      0
7   jkl     hello JKL!      0
8   jkl     hello JKL2!     0
9   jkl     hello JKL3!     0
10  jkl     hello JKL4!     0
```